# Views doesn't split content into seprates list items

Tags: views, theming, 6

I need to produce a list of images with views 3 but these group items in only one li element...like this:

```
    <ul class="rslides">   
       <li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">  
              <div class="field-item field-item-0">
<img src="//xxx:3000/sites/all/media/imagecache/MG_illustration_170x310/diapo_lycee/2017/22/abstract-h-c-1107-1142-8.jpg" alt="Lycée Marie Gasquet" title="Lycée Marie Gasquet" width="170" height="310" ></div>
    <div class="field-item field-item-1">
<img src="//xx:3000/sites/all/media/imagecache/MG_illustration_170x310/diapo_lycee/2017/22/city-q-c-640-480-4.jpg" >
</div>
  </li>
          </ul>
```

How can I force it to put items in is proper li element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all of these images are in a multi-value field:

1. Make sure your view is showing "Fields" instead of "Teaser" or some other display setting
2. Add your multi-value image field through the Fields section "Add" button
3. Configure the field by clicking on it. You should see a pop-up window with collapsible sections at the bottom - the top section is "Multiple Field Settings". Open that section. Turn on the setting "Display all values in the same row"; when you click that, it'll open the "Display Type" options, for which you'll pick either "Ordered list" or "Unordered list" (assuming unordered list, since you use  in the question's code).